# Get the number of Days in the current month using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the need to retrieve the number of days in the current month, and despite my research, I have yet to find anything in powershell that does it.  The following is what I have currently built to get the result I want.  is there a better way to do it?

Please note that I am limited to Powershell

```
    #check to see if this is a leap year
    function LYC
    {
        if ([System.DateTime]::isleapyear((Get-Date).Year))
        {
            $Global:LY = True
        }
    }
    #Get the number of days in current month
    function fNOD
    {
        $MNum = (Get-Date).Month
        switch ($MNum)
        {
            1   {$Global:DaysInMonth=31}
            2   {
                    LYC
                    if (LY)
                    {
                        $Global:DaysInMonth=29
                    } else {
                        $Global:DaysInMonth=28
                    }
                }
            3   {$Global:DaysInMonth=31}
            4   {$Global:DaysInMonth=30}
            5   {$Global:DaysInMonth=31}
            6   {$Global:DaysInMonth=30}
            7   {$Global:DaysInMonth=31}
            8   {$Global:DaysInMonth=31}
            9   {$Global:DaysInMonth=30}
            10  {$Global:DaysInMonth=31}
            11  {$Global:DaysInMonth=30}
            12  {$Global:DaysInMonth=31}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx

```
# static int DaysInMonth(int year, int month)
[DateTime]::DaysInMonth(2013, 3)
```

Comment: I suggested $numDays = ((Get-Date -Month 3) - (Get-Date -Month 2)) ; That said, .NET is always another great route to go!

Comment: +1 sound good you can just finish `[datetime]::DaysInMonth([datetime]::Now.year,[datetime]::Now.month)`

Comment: yep and `(Get-Date).Month` `(Get-Date).Year`

Comment: Or: `[datetime]::DaysInMonth((date).Year,(date).Month)` - anyways, great tip to get accurate results :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want it for any date stored in `$date`:

```
((get-date $date -Day 1 -hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0).AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1)).Day
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like it might be deceptively easy:

```
$numDays = ((Get-Date -Month 3) - (Get-Date -Month 2))
```

28 days in February, July minus June gives me 30 days.

As mentioned below, that apparently sometimes does some weird integer rounding that gives off 29d, 23h, 59m or something else not right.

This seems to be consistent:

```
$monthLess = Get-Date -Month 4
$NumDays = (Get-Date -Month 5).Subtract($monthLess)
```

Comment: ;o) what about : `(Get-Date -Month 5)-(Get-Date -Month 4)` gives 29.D 23h 59m 59s on my computer.

Comment: @JPBlanc I've got the same result only the first time I used your code... all the next retry give 30 day...

Comment: Weird, I can get 30 every time with only (Get-Date -Month 5)-(Get-Date -Month 4), but if I do my original ((Get-Date -Month 5)-(Get-Date -Month 4)) then it will randomly throw 29d.59m.59s.

I am adding what I found above